# Tests fail with @Scheduled Task: JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException Table "USER_ACCOUNT_CREATED_EVENT" not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

## Summary & first problem

I am trying to test my user registration mechanism. When a new user account is created via my REST API, a `UserAccountCreatedEvent` is stored in the database. A scheduled task checks the database every 5 seconds for new `UserAccountCreatedEvent`s and if one is present, sends an email to the registered user. When running my tests I encounter the problem that the table for the `UserAccountCreatedEvent` can't be found (see exception below). I used to send the email in a blocking manner in the service method, but I recently switched to this async approach. All my tests worked perfectly for the blocking approach and the only thing I changed for the async approach is to include `Awaitility` in the test.

```
2019-04-23 11:24:51.605 ERROR 7968 --- [taskScheduler-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select useraccoun0_.id as id1_0_, useraccoun0_.completed_at as complete2_0_, useraccoun0_.created_at as created_3_0_, useraccoun0_.in_process_since as in_proce4_0_, useraccoun0_.status as status5_0_, useraccoun0_.user_id as user_id1_35_ from user_account_created_event useraccoun0_ where useraccoun0_.status=? order by useraccoun0_.created_at asc limit ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException:
Table "USER_ACCOUNT_CREATED_EVENT" not found; SQL statement:
select useraccoun0_.id as id1_0_, useraccoun0_.completed_at as complete2_0_, useraccoun0_.created_at as created_3_0_, useraccoun0_.in_process_since as in_proce4_0_, useraccoun0_.status as status5_0_, useraccoun0_.user_id as user_id1_35_ from user_account_created_event useraccoun0_ where useraccoun0_.status=? order by useraccoun0_.created_at asc limit ? [42102-199]
```

[Full stack trace](https://pastebin.com/mdufrcUt)

---

## Second problem

As if that were not enough, the tests behave completely different when running them in debug mode. When I set a breakpoint in the method that is called by the method which is annotated with `@Scheduled`, it is invoked several times althogh `@Scheduled` is configured with a `fixedDelayString` (fixed delay) of 5000ms. Thanks to logging I can even see that several mails were sent. Still, my test SMTP sever (`GreenMail`) does not receive any emails. How is this even possible? I've intentionally set the transaction isolation to `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` so that it should be impossible  (as far as I understand transaction isolation) that two scheduled methods access the same Event from the database.

---

## Third problem

To cap it all, when I rerun the failed tests, THEY WORK. But, there are different exceptions on the console (see below). But still, the app starts and the tests finish successfully. There are different test results depending on if I run all tests vs. only the class vs. only the method vs. rerun failed tests. I don't understand how such an indeterministic behaviour can be possible.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Failed to scan classpath for unlisted entity classes

Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException: null
```

[Full stack trace](https://pastebin.com/LSFbUgaE)

[image: Five tests fail]
[image: Rerun and they work]

---

## My code

### Test class (`UserRegistrationTest`)

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class UserRegistrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private Routes routes;

    @Autowired
    private TestConfig testConfig;

    @Resource(name = "validCustomerDTO")
    private CustomerDTO validCustomerDTO;

    @Resource(name = "validVendorDTO")
    private VendorRegistrationDTO validVendorRegistrationDTO;

    @Value("${schedule.sendRegistrationConfirmationEmailTaskDelay}")
    private Short registrationConfirmationEmailSenderTaskDelay;

    private GreenMail smtpServer;

    // Setup & tear down

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        smtpServer = testConfig.getMailServer();
        smtpServer.start();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        smtpServer.stop();
    }

    // Tests

    @Test
    public void testCreateCustomerAccount() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
            post(routes.getCustomerPath())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(validCustomerDTO)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        // When run normally, I get a timeout from the next line
        await().atMost(registrationConfirmationEmailSenderTaskDelay + 10000, MILLISECONDS).until(smtpServerReceivedOneEmail());

        // Verify correct registration confirmation email was sent
        MimeMessage[] receivedMessages = smtpServer.getReceivedMessages();
        assertThat(receivedMessages).hasSize(1);

        // other checks
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateVendorAccount() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
            post(routes.getVendorPath())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(validVendorRegistrationDTO)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        // When run normally, I get a timeout from the next line
        await().atMost(registrationConfirmationEmailSenderTaskDelay + 10000, MILLISECONDS).until(smtpServerReceivedOneEmail());

        // Verify correct registration confirmation email was sent
        MimeMessage[] receivedMessages = smtpServer.getReceivedMessages();
        assertThat(receivedMessages).hasSize(1);

        // other checks
        // ...
    }

    // Helper methods

    private Callable<Boolean> smtpServerReceivedOneEmail() {
        return () -> smtpServer.getReceivedMessages().length == 1;
    }

    // Test configuration

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        private static final int PORT = 3025;
        private static final String HOST = "localhost";
        private static final String PROTOCOL = "smtp";

        GreenMail getMailServer() {
            return new GreenMail(new ServerSetup(PORT, HOST, PROTOCOL));
        }

        @Bean
        public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
            JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
            javaMailSender.setHost(HOST);
            javaMailSender.setPort(PORT);
            javaMailSender.setProtocol(PROTOCOL);
            javaMailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            return javaMailSender;
        }
    }
```

### Task scheduler (`BusinessTaskScheduler`)

```
@Component
public class BusinessTaskScheduler {

    private final RegistrationTask registrationTask;

    @Autowired
    public BusinessTaskScheduler(RegistrationTask registrationTask) {
        this.registrationTask = registrationTask;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${schedule.sendRegistrationConfirmationEmailTaskDelay}")
    public void sendRegistrationConfirmationEmail() {
        registrationTask.sendRegistrationConfirmationEmail();
    }
}
```

### The code that is called by the scheduled method (`RegistrationTask`)

```
@Component
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public class RegistrationTask {

    private final EmailHelper emailHelper;
    private final EventService eventService;
    private final UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService;

    @Autowired
    public RegistrationTask(EmailHelper emailHelper, EventService eventService, UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService) {
        this.emailHelper = emailHelper;
        this.eventService = eventService;
        this.userRegistrationService = userRegistrationService;
    }

    public void sendRegistrationConfirmationEmail() {
        Optional<UserAccountCreatedEvent> optionalEvent = eventService.getOldestUncompletedUserAccountCreatedEvent();
        if (optionalEvent.isPresent()) {
            UserAccountCreatedEvent event = optionalEvent.get();
            User user = event.getUser();
            RegistrationVerificationToken token = userRegistrationService.createRegistrationVerificationTokenForUser(user);
            emailHelper.sendRegistrationConfirmationEmail(token);
            eventService.completeEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

### The event service (`EventServiceImpl`)

```
@Service
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {

    private final ApplicationEventDAO applicationEventDAO;
    private final UserAccountCreatedEventDAO userAccountCreatedEventDAO;

    @Autowired
    public EventServiceImpl(ApplicationEventDAO applicationEventDAO, UserAccountCreatedEventDAO userAccountCreatedEventDAO) {
        this.applicationEventDAO = applicationEventDAO;
        this.userAccountCreatedEventDAO = userAccountCreatedEventDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public void completeEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (!event.getStatus().equals(COMPLETED) && Objects.isNull(event.getCompletedAt())) {
            event.setStatus(COMPLETED);
            event.setCompletedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
            applicationEventDAO.save(event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<UserAccountCreatedEvent> getOldestUncompletedUserAccountCreatedEvent() {
        Optional<UserAccountCreatedEvent> optionalEvent = userAccountCreatedEventDAO.findFirstByStatusOrderByCreatedAtAsc(NEW);
        if (optionalEvent.isPresent()) {
            UserAccountCreatedEvent event = optionalEvent.get();
            setEventInProcess(event);
            return Optional.of(userAccountCreatedEventDAO.save(event));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public void publishEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        applicationEventDAO.save(event);
    }

    // Helper methods

    private void setEventInProcess(ApplicationEvent event) {
        event.setStatus(Status.IN_PROCESS);
        event.setInProcessSince(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

### The `UserAccountCreatedEvent`

[image: UML]

### `application.yml`

```
schedule:
  sendRegistrationConfirmationEmailTaskDelay: 5000 # delay between tasks in milliseconds
```

I am new to scheduling with Spring, so any help is greatly appreciated!